# Use python 2 shelf in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have data stored in a shelf file created with python 2.7

When I try to access the file from python 3.4, I get an error:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> population=shelve.open('shelved.shelf')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shelve.py", line 239, in open
    return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shelve.py", line 223, in __init__
    Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\dbm\__init__.py", line 88, in open
    raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
dbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

I'm still able to access the shelf with no problem in python 2.7, so there seems to be a backward-compatibility issue. Is there any way to directly access the old format with the new python version?

Comment: Yup, I can reproduce this.

Comment: Can't you just convert the source to 3 using the [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand now, here is the path that lead to my problem:

- The original shelf was created with Python 2 in Windows
- Python 2 Windows defaults to bsddb as the underlying database for shelving, since dbm is not available on the Windows platform
- Python 3 does not ship with bsddb. The underlying database is dumbdbm in Python 3 for Windows.

I at first looked into installing a third party bsddb module for Python 3, but it quickly started to turn into a hassle. It then seemed that it would be a recurring hassle any time I need to use the same shelf file on a new machine. So I decided to convert the file from bsddb to dumbdbm, which both my python 2 and python 3 installations can read.

I ran the following in Python 2, which is the version that contains both bsddb and dumbdbm:

```
import shelve
import dumbdbm

def dumbdbm_shelve(filename,flag="c"):
    return shelve.Shelf(dumbdbm.open(filename,flag))

out_shelf=dumbdbm_shelve("shelved.dumbdbm.shelf")
in_shelf=shelve.open("shelved.shelf")

key_list=in_shelf.keys()
for key in key_list:
    out_shelf[key]=in_shelf[key]

out_shelf.close()
in_shelf.close()
```

So far it looks like the dumbdbm.shelf files came out ok, pending a double-check of the contents.

Comment: Thanks very much to all for the thoughts and tips.

Comment: This worked for Python versions 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 running on stock Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Hi, after following above process, Below are the files getting generated: 1. shelved.dumbdbm.shelf.bak  2. shelved.dumbdbm.shelf.dat 3. shelved.dumbdbm.shelf.dir 4. shelved.shelf.        I tried reading `model = shelve.open('shelved.dumbdbm.shelf') `. Getting an empty model.   Also tried to read newly generated `shelved.shelf`, getting same db type error. can you please help me resolving this error? I am using models from here(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e0t37fpq9j226yw/AAD4O_4SZ6jB5jpu9QCiJ9PJa?dl=0). I want to use these models in python3

Comment: "shelved.dumbdbm.shelf" and "shelved.shelf" are only intended as example names. You should replace those with names that match your own case. in_shelf is the existing file being read, so to convert the file in your dropbox you should use in_shelf=shelve.open("wiki.shelve")
out_self in this case could be "wiki.dumbdbm.shelve", or any other name you choose.

Answer (score 3):

The `shelve` module uses Python's [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), which may require a protocol version when being accessed between different versions of Python.

Try supplying protocol version 2:

```
population = shelve.open('shelved.shelf', protocol=2)
```

According to the documentation:

> Protocol version 2 was introduced in Python 2.3. It provides much more efficient pickling of new-style classes. Refer to PEP 307 for information about improvements brought by protocol 2.

This is most likely the protocol used in the original serialization (or pickling).

Comment: Verified that this does NOT work for Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Note: This answer "working" depends on which protocol was used to store the information and using the same protocol to retrieve it. There are now protocol versions `0` and `4`—only trying version `2` (as I suggest) will not universally work. It also assumes the error is a result of a protocol version mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Edited: You may need to rename your database. Read on...

Seems like `pickle` is not the culprit here. `shelve` relies also in `anydbm` (Python 2.x) or `dbm` (Python 3) to create/open a database and store the pickled information.

I created (manually) a database file using the following:

```
# Python 2.7
import anydbm
anydbm.open('database2', flag='c')
```

and

```
# Python 3.4
import dbm
dbm.open('database3', flag='c')
```

In both cases, it creates the same kind of database (may be distribution dependent, this is on Debian 7):

```
$ file *
database2:    Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
database3.db: Berkeley DB (Hash, version 9, native byte-order)
```

`anydbm` can open `database3.db` without problems, as expected:

```
>>> anydbm.open('database3')
<dbm.dbm object at 0x7fb1089900f0>
```

Notice the lack of `.db` when specifying the database name, though. But `dbm` *chokes* on `database2`, which is weird:

```
>>> dbm.open('database2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dbm/__init__.py", line 88, in open
    raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
dbm.error: db type could not be determined
```

unless I change the name of the name of the database to `database2.db`:

```
$ mv database2 database2.db
$ python3
>>> import dbm
>>> dbm.open('database2')
<_dbm.dbm object at 0x7fa7eaefcf50>
```

So, I suspect a regression on the `dbm` module, but I haven't checked the documentation. It may be intended :-?

NB: Notice that in my case, the extension is `.db`, but that depends on the database being used by `dbm` by default! Create an empty shelf using Python 3 to figure out which one are you using and what is it expecting.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to do it--

Comment: As an additional problem, it may be that your platform uses different default databases for `anydbm` and `dbm`. In my case is the same, but it is not for @HenryKeiter

Comment: I found a post that indicates the trouble could be from a lack of Berkeley db support in python 3. Trying to figure out how to install a 3rd party module to see if this will help. Referenced post is at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/montrealpython/5TGZsB46rkE

Comment: Yes, probably-- however, this started to turn into a pain. The installation instructions tell Windows users to run the installer, but there's no installer to be found for Python 3. When I started seeing instructions for compiling the Berkeley db with Visual Studio, I decided it was time for plan B     :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use a Python 2 shelf with Python 3's `shelve` module. The underlying files are completely different, at least in my tests.

In **Python 2***, a shelf is represented as a single file with the filename you originally gave it.

In **Python 3***, a shelf consists of *three* files: `filename.bak`, `filename.dat`, and `filename.dir`. Without any of these files present, the shelf cannot be opened by the Python 3 library (though it appears that just the `.dat` file is sufficient for *opening*, if not actual reading).

[@Ricardo Cárdenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27493814/2069350) has given an overview of why this may be--it's likely an issue with the underlying database modules used in storing the shelved data. It's possible that the databases are backwards compatible, but I don't know and a quick search hasn't turned up any obvious answers.

I think it's likely that *some* of the possible databases implemented by `dbm` *are* backwards-compatible, whereas others are not: this could be the cause of the discrepancy between answers here, where some people, but not all, are able to open older databases directly by specifying a protocol.

---

*On every machine I've tested, using Python 2.7.6 vs Pythons 3.2.5, 3.3.4, and 3.4.1

Comment: Did you test this before you downvoted? Python3 `protocol=2` does work.

Comment: @JacobBudin Of course I tested it. `protocol=2` results in exactly the same error.

Comment: @HenryKeiter Just because your shelf interface is different for your Python major versions, doesn't mean that's true for everyone.

Comment: @JacobBudin The asker specifies 2.7 and 3.X. `protocol=2` produces `dmb.error: db type could not be determined` in 3.2.5, 3.3.4, and 3.4.1, when attempting to open a 2.7.6 shelved file.

Comment: Also, note that `protocol=2` is not used **unless** specified. The default one for Python 2 is `protocol=0`

Answer (score 0):

The berkeleydb module includes a retro-compatible
implementation of the shelve object. (You will also need to install Oracle Berkeley DB)

You just need to:

```py
import berkeleydb
from berkeleydb import dbshelve as shelve

population = shelve.open('shelved.shelf')
```

Comment: I think the first line in the code snippet has a typo: import berkleydb should be import berkeleydb