# Can't open shelf in python -- DBInvalidArgError (Python 2.4)

Tags: python, shelve

```
selectedfile = ""
    while selectedfile == "":
        print "\t\t ~Episodes With Scores~"
    for filename in datfiles:
        #prints filename without .dat
        print "\n\t\t" + filename[0:-4]
    selectedfile = raw_input("\n\nType the name of the episode you want     to see scores for.")
    selectedfile = selectedfile + ".dat"
    highscores = shelve.open(selectedfile, "r")
```

After this code, specifically when I try to open the selected file, I'm greeted with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "D:\Trivia Challenge\trivia_2.py", line 463, in -toplevel-
>    File "D:\Trivia Challenge\trivia_2.py", line 454, in main
>    File "D:\Trivia Challenge\trivia_2.py", line 293, in get_high_scores
>    File "shelve.pyc", line 231, in open
>    File "shelve.pyc", line 212, in **init**
>    File "anydbm.pyc", line 83, in open
>    File "dbhash.pyc", line 16, in open
>    File "bsddb__init__.pyc", line 299, in hashopen
>   DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- .\tutorial.dat: unsupported     >hash version: 9')

It works with python.exe, but using the python shell it gives an error.

Comment: You might have different version of python installed, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27493814/29489

Comment: Do not use `shelve`, use `sqlite` instead as it is not as version specific.